# How to append text to multiple files

Tags: c#, file-io

I am not a programmer, but I am a researcher and I need to modify some files.
I have a number of text files with *.mol extension located in c:\abc\ directory . I need to append line containing following    text "M  END" to each file in this list. I tried following in C# but without any result:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\abc\\*.mol", true); 
            sw.WriteLine("M  END"); 
            sw.Close();   

        }
    }
}
```

Please, suggest the solution.

Thank You!

Comment: Why are you using C# in the first place. You seem to have some kind of bash experience, why not try to use PowerShell ?

Answer (score 7):

Would you be satisfied with this oneliner that you can put in any DOS batch (.bat) file:

```
FOR %%I IN (c:\abc\*.mol) DO ECHO M  END>>%%I
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("directory", "*.mol"))
{
    File.AppendAllText(fileName, Environment.NewLine + "M  END");
}
```

Comment: +1 for using AppendAllText (my solution used ReadAllText and WriteAllText because I did not know about AppendAllText). Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through all the files matching that pattern and write to them individually. The `StreamWriter` constructor you're using only supports writing to an individual file ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx)).

You can get a list of files using:

```
 string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\abc\\", "*.mol");
```

Comment: Thats good unless you run into a file that is locked or you don't have permissions to. then the entire thing fails ( that might be a good thing in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the files in the directory. DirectoryInfo / FileInfo makes it easy to do this. Also, since you want to append to the end, you need to seek the stream before writing your signature at the end.

Here's a solution that works solely at that location. You will need to add recursive support to descend into subdirectories if desired.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace appender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void AppendToFile(FileInfo fi)
        {
            if (!fi.Exists) { return; }

            using (Stream stm = fi.OpenWrite())
            {
                stm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

                using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    output.WriteLine("M  END");
                    output.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\abc\\");
            FileInfo[] fiItems = di.GetFiles("*.mol");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in fiItems)
            {
                AppendToFile(fi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stream is not a good choice when File.AppendAllText will achieve the same result in a single line.