# Is there any good way to see where a variable is coming from?

Tags: php

I'm tracing back a variable, I can print out the value of that variable, but I don't know where(which page) this value has been passed to the variable. Is there any good way to print out where actually this value is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recap of debugging and some gotchas.

There is no programmatic way to determine where a variable "spawned" into existence in PHP.

Good debugging skills are your friend.  Do check out the other answers posted.  Recapped here:

1. `debug_print_backtrace()` - to let you know what files are included.
2. Use `grep -rn 'variable_name' .` from the top level of your site to see where it exists.
3. Add `var_dump($variable)` in a bunch of places one at a time can help as well to track down what the variable was in different states.

Also:
Using a good debugger can help out quite a bit.  One widely used debugger extension is Xdebug.

Two potential gotchas to look for are: `eval()` and `extract()`
Both of these can "magically" cause variables to exist that didn't before.

Of course, the best way to fix this problem is to not have global variables.  Or at least have as few as possible.  You can have a well defined flow to your code, whether it's MVC or something else.  Then you'll know the order your code is executed in and where variables are instantiated and/or passed around.

Answer (score 5):

A good starting point would be the [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) function. It won't trace where a variable has been passed per se, but it will show you all the functions and included/required files with line numbers.

Comment: Is there any function can be used like function_name($variable) to see where the variable is coming from. I tried debug_print_backtrace(), it just printed out which pages have been included, but there are too many pages, I can't check all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check $_POST /$_GET variables in the pages which you are backtracing. Are you sure if you are not able to find the variable using grep/search utility?

Comment: I used grep to search and found the original of the $variable, but I'm not sure whether it's the correct place. Another thing is the $variable has been passed via several pages, I want to know all of the pages.

Comment: Probably you add a print statement to print value of that variable across each pages. If you want to do that this using a program then  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538094/how-to-append-text-to-multiple-files should help you. Another approach is to add a piece to code to append variable value to file with page name. You could check this file after you navigate across your pages to see variable value across each page

Answer (score 1):

If you're in linux, you can type:

```
grep -rn "variable_name" .
```

to view the files (and the line numbers on those files) that the variable is referenced.

I always like to test my assumptions too. So if you suspect that the variable might be changed on a page, you can type:

```
var_dump( $variable_name );
```

To see the value. By moving that around, you'll be able to zero in on it and find the source of the variable being set.

I hope that helps...